# Get Latest from Python Sorted() Not Working in Django

Tags: python, django

I am combining two Django Queryset and I want to be able to get the latest 10 out of the combo. I want to display them in descending order, of date, in my template - so that **the latest Articles gets displayed first**.

```
import itertools

articles = Articles.object.filter(conditions)[:10]
shared_articles = Shares.object.filter(conditions)[:10]

all_articles = sorted(itertools.chain(articles, shared_articles), 
                      key=lambda x: x.date_created, reverse=True)[-10:]
```

Now if I do the following in my template, **the oldest articles get displayed first**:

```
{% for article in all_articles %}
    <h3>{{article.header}}</h3>
    <p>{{article.content}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I get it to display the latest first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can used `reversed` in [`for` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{% for article in all_articles reversed %}
    <h3>{{article.header}}</h3>
    <p>{{article.content}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```